# Array_push() without key index

Tags: php

**I have looked at other answers for the same question, but the answers given were alternatives due to what the OP were trying to achieve. Those solutions wouldn't work for me.**

```
$data = array();
$data['MilestoneCollection'] = array();
array_push($data['MilestoneCollection'],  array("Milestone" => array("Description" => "1", "EventCode" => "1")));
array_push($data['MilestoneCollection'],  array("Milestone" => array("Description" => "2", "EventCode" => "2")));
print_r($data);
```

This outputs:

```
Array
(
    [MilestoneCollection] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Milestone] => Array
                        (
                            [Description] => 1
                            [EventCode] => 1
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Milestone] => Array
                        (
                            [Description] => 2
                            [EventCode] => 2
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Expected:

```
Array
(
    [MilestoneCollection] => Array
        (
            [Milestone] => Array
                (
                    [Description] => 1
                    [EventCode] => 1
                )
            [Milestone] => Array
                (
                    [Description] => 2
                    [EventCode] => 2
                )
        )

)
```

I tried to use:

```
$data['MilestoneCollection'] = array("Milestone" => array("Description" => "1","EventCode" => "1"));        
$data['MilestoneCollection'] = array("Milestone" => array("Description" => "2","EventCode" => "2"));
```

but this results in the first one being overwritten. What is the correct way to achieve what I need?

Comment: So you want two equals keys? I think it's not possible the way you want.

Comment: Ultimately I need to convert this to XML, which allows multiple keys of the same name.

Comment: Append the data as array inside Milestone: `$data['MilestoneCollection']['Milestone'][] = ['Description ....`

Comment: @FelippeDuarte This causes the indexes to be shown as in the first example.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to have multiple keys that match as per the XML spec I have to match, I think I need to go about this a different way.

Comment: Deal with it in the code that converts to XML. It should loop over the array and create elements with the same tag.

Comment: You can't use arrays with duplicate keys as proxy to generate XML because such data structure does not exist in PHP. I don't know your use case, but you can normally just generate XML directly.

Comment: @Barmar I tried but run into some more issues.

Comment: Instead I took @ÁlvaroGonzález advice and just learnt how to create the XML directly, which worked fine and as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would perhaps approach it, using an export of an example as a guide for creating the import.

```
$in = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<milestonecollection>
  <milestone>
    <description>1</description>
    <eventcode>1</eventcode>
  </milestone>
  <milestone>
    <description>2</description>
    <eventcode>2</eventcode>
  </milestone>
</milestonecollection>
XML;

$inbound = new SimpleXMLElement($in);

print_r($inbound);
```

This produces:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [milestone] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [description] => 1
                    [eventcode] => 1
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [description] => 2
                    [eventcode] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

Simplistically, we'd be looking something like:

```
$out = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>
<milestonecollection></milestonecollection>
XML;

$outbound = new SimpleXMLElement($out);

$milestone1 = $outbound->addChild('milestone');
$milestone1->addChild('description', 1);
$milestone1->addChild('eventcode', 1);

$milestone2 = $outbound->addChild('milestone');
$milestone2->addChild('description', 2);
$milestone2->addChild('eventcode', 2);

echo $outbound->asXML();
```

If the number of `milestone` elements to include is static, you're good. If they're not, you can iterate your list like the below.

```
$i = 1;
$collection = [
    'milestones' => [
        [
            'description' => $i,
            'eventcode' => $i++
        ],[
            'description' => $i
            'eventcode' => $i++
        ],[
            'description' => $i
            'eventcode' => $i++
        ],[
            'description' => $i,
            'eventcode' => $i
        ]
    ]
];

$milestones = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>
<milestonecollection></milestonecollection>
XML;

$export = new SimpleXMLElement($milestones);

foreach($collection['milestones'] as $item) {
    $milestone = $export->addChild('milestone');

    foreach($item as $type => $value) {
        $milestone->addChild($type, $value);
    }
}

echo $export->asXML();
```

https://3v4l.org/4OtD4